# Wordpress change Autentication From username to email

Tags: php, wordpress

How or where I must edit wordpress to make user autentication with email and not with username (as it is default)

Comment: This has been asked on [Wordpress Stackexchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51678/how-to-login-with-email-only-no-username)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, add this to the functions.php file:

```
// remove the default filter
remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20, 3 );
// add custom filter
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'fb_authenticate_username_password', 20, 3 );
function fb_authenticate_username_password( $user, $username, $password ) {

// If an email address is entered in the username box, 
// then look up the matching username and authenticate as per normal, using that.
if ( ! empty( $username ) )
    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $username );

if ( isset( $user->user_login, $user ) )
    $username = $user->user_login;

// using the username found when looking up via email
return wp_authenticate_username_password( NULL, $username, $password );
}
```

(The above was found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51714) and I tested it and worked for me)

EDIT: [This](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-email-login/) plugin works as well if you don't want to modify the functions file.

Comment: Can you tell me where is this function.php located?

Comment: On the dashboard go to Appearance -> Editor and on the right hand side find the file called functions.php

Comment: @baxri, I had added a link to a plugin that will do the same thing as well if you don't want to edit the functions file.